# Как найти и удалить драйвер принтера

Tags: linux, принтер

Как полностью удалить драйвер из системы? ОС - debian 8, принтер canon mf-3010. Посносил вроде все пакеты, которые ставил, но, при выполнении команды `hwinfo --printer | grep Model` показывает `Model: "Canon MF3010"` как мне найти, какой пакет(ы) еще нужно удалить чтобы полностью убрать упоминания об этом принтере?

Comment: принтер надо отключить, чтобы не было про него упоминаний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поищите упоминания принтера в файлах в директориях cups:

```
$ grep -r 'MF3010' /usr/share/cups/
```

Если найдёте файл, найдите пакет к которому он относится:

```
$ dpkg -S '/usr/share/cups/....'
```

Кроме того если принтер был установлен, в каталоге `/etc/cups/ppd` есть файл описывающий его, и в /etc/cups/printers.conf он тоже может быть упомянут, последний файл может содержать пароли доступа к принтерам, поэтому читается только суперпользователем.

Comment: спасибо, помогло